# Upgrade django-allauth to newer version maintaining migration

Tags: python, django, migration, django-allauth

I was using django alluth with django 1.7. Now we shifted to django 1.10, and and we need to upgrade django allauth to 0.27.

I can do it by reinstalling the package with pip but I am concerned about the migration files already present there.

What should be the ideal way to upgrade it to a new version without losing the migrations?

Comment: What do you mean by, _migration files_?

Comment: the migration files that are created on running makemigrations command for creating and sync-ing database in django

Comment: Get the DB dump from the live environment and try it all out locally. Speculation about issues that might arise will not help you when you haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: I have worked on those things and handling migrations is not a big deal for me. I am asking about any best practices or something I might be missing.